# На htc android 4.2 по нажатию push(а), activity не открывается

Tags: android

На htc, android 4.2 по нажатию push(а), activity не открывается. на других устройствах работает, в чем может быть проблема?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_gooto)
                .setContentInfo(formatTime)
                .setContentTitle(name)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(message))
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{500, 500, 500})
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setPriority(2)
                .setTicker(message);

        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21250686/3212712) можно попробовать такие варианты:

1. Использовать флаг `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` вместо `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`
2. В манифесте добавить в тег активити атрибут `android:exported="true"`
3. Дополнить ещё одним флагом `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT`